# Try and except ValueError is no working in my Number guessing game

Tags: python

Just started to learn python yesterday, I am creating a simple number guessing game and it all works except Try and except value error.

```py
import random
import math
lower = 0
upper = 100
def game():
    lower = 0
    upper = 100
    x = random.randint(lower, upper)
    print(x)

    times = 0

    while True:

        guess = int(input("Guess:- "))
        times += 1

        try:
            guess = int(guess)
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid number")

        if x == guess:
            print(f"Boom! Answer is {x}.")
            print("\nAfter", times, " You pass the game!\n")
            return
        if upper <= guess or guess <= lower:
            print("Not this range! Try again!")
        elif x < guess:
            print(f"Now it is {lower} to {guess}")
            upper =int(guess)
        elif x > guess:
            print(f"Now it is {guess} to {upper}")
            lower = int(guess)
    return

def main():
    
    print("\n[*** You're playing Guessing number from", lower, "to", upper, "***]\n")

    while True:
        game()

        play_again = input('play again? y/n: ') == 'y'
        if not play_again:
            return 
        if play_again:
            print("\n[Again!]\n")
main()
```

when I type sth like "a" it still show error as:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'`
I found some solution that seems to work with other's number games but sadly not for me, I wonder what the problem is.

Comment: `guess = int(input("Guess:- "))` you first convert your input to int here, which is not in a try/except statement, which is why you get an error. The second conversion in `guess = int(guess)` doesn't do anything as it tries to convert from int (as it should already be converted by then) to int

Comment: "it still show error as" Okay, so when you **read the entire error message**, do you notice how it **tells you where** the error occurred? Is that line inside the `try`? No, it is not.

Comment: I got it worked now! I i think it is because there are two `guess` since I change one of `guess` to `number` and remove the `int` which suddenly makes it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, the problem is that `int()` is run already without the try/except block, which means that you will still have an unhandled error. You can fix this by changing `guess = int(input("Guess:- "))` to `guess = input("Guess:- ")`. However, you can also change the whole block to use an if statement instead, like this:

```
guess = input("Guess:- ")
times += 1

if (guess.isdigit()):
    guess = int(guess)
else:
    print("Not a valid number")
    break
```